# How do I write to file and assign in the same function?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I have written a function which outputs a text file, but I also want to assign it to an object to use later. I cannot find a way to do this within the same function. For example, this outputs a text file using fwrite:

```
de_genes <- function(fit, j, name) {
  topTable(fit, coef = j, number = Inf, sort.by = 'none') %>%
    select(Gene, AvgExpr, logFC, p.value, q.value) %>% 
    fwrite(paste0('./', name, '_', cell, '.txt'), sep = '\t')
}
```

Assigning it to an object (temp) and then writing to an output does not assign it to an object, e.g.

```
  de_genes <- function(fit, j, name) {
    topTable(fit, coef = j, number = Inf, sort.by = 'none') %>%
    select(Gene, AvgExpr, logFC, p.value, q.value) -> temp
    fwrite(temp, paste0('./', name, '_', cell, '.txt'), sep = '\t')
}
```

Nor does assigning the output to the function to an object (value of NULL)

```
temp <- de_genes(fit, j = 2, 'example')
```

Comment: Make the last line of the function something that will return the data frame, i.e. `return(temp)` or just `temp`

Comment: if I use ```temp <- return(temp)``` or ```return(temp)``` as the last line of the function, it prints it to the console but does not assign it to an object.

Comment: I see, you're misunderstanding how scoping works. The object `temp` *outside* the function doesn't know about the object `temp` *inside* the function—that's a concept in a lot of languages. You could assign it in the global environment from inside the function, but that's generally not a good idea. Much better is to have the function return your output, then assign the result of the function call